# Use scrbook but can also compile subchapters

Tags: koma-script, compiling

I have the following structure

```
chapter1/
chapter2/
...
main.tex
preamble.tex
```

And I have a main.tex that looks like this

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\input{preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
\input{chapter1/main.tex}
...
\end{document}
```

And each of the subfolder's `main.tex` looks like this

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\input{../preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
...content...
\end{document}
```

In order to reduce compile time, I always work on each chapter and run `main.tex` only occasionally. But when I compile it throws the following error

```
LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
```

It seems to complain about the chapter's `main.tex` also includes the `preamble.tex`. I wonder what is the best walkthrough to this scenario that both separate chapters into subfolders but also able to compile each chapter seperately.

Thank you!

Comment: Loading the `standalone` package in your preamble for the scrbook main.tex may help, as it is supposed to skip extra preambles in included files. However, it is difficult to test with the information given here.

Comment: Welcome. // Not sure, if you can "save" compile time in Latex like you might in C or similar languages. // However, why don't you strip your main.tex in the chapter folders to just content AND have a separate maincontrol.tex in those folders, with pramble as you show AND include yourchapters content? This way you could contol content and presentation to some degree, if it's that what you want. And if you include this stripped main.tex in your top-file, everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @henryflower, `standalone` works!! Maybe you can write a short answer and I will accept yours

Comment: Ah @MS-SPO, good point, I am still new to managing subfiles, what you purposed makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`standalone`](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package, when loaded in the preamble of your `scrbook` main.tex, will skip all extra preambles from included files.